# may I post here limericks asking for the last line?

Tags: discussion

I have a paper pack book with a nice collection of "shocking" limericks (some may be for certain people a little bit obscene. but principle I think this might be a good idea to post a limerick and ask for the punchline (the "pointe".)

**Example:**

A priest and a shepherd from Australia participate in a TV game. After answering all the questions, there is a tie. So both are given one final assignment. It is to write a poem in three minutes, using the word "Timbuktu". It is a city in Africa.
The priest returns with the fruit of his inspiration:Edit
"I was a father all my life,
I had no children, had no wife,
I read the bible through and through 
on my way to Timbuktu ... "

The poem makes a great impression, and the priest smells a sweet victory. But then comes the shepherd, with his winning masterpiece:

When Tim and I to Melbourne went

there were three women in a tent

as they were three and we were two

I booked one and Tim booked two

**source:**
http://thebestjokes.wikia.com/wiki/Tim_booked_two

I would just ask it this way:

When Tim and I to Melbourne went

there were three women in a tent

as they were three and we were two

.....................................................

**(write a punch line)**

If you agree we could create a new tag:
**punch line**

and the question will be:

what is the punch line of .....  ?

Answer (score 2):

While this could be a fun and entertaining exercise, this is *not* an appropriate question for Puzzling.SE.  Questions here must have **one** answer which is **objectively best** (according to criteria laid out in the question).

The type of question proposed above

1. is not about the creation and solving of puzzles
2. cannot (by definition) have *one, objectively correct* answer.

If you had the interest of others, you could potentially try something like this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com), by creating a specific room for it.